# Portable battery charger: how can I recharge the batteries without direct connection to my home electricity?

Tags: arduino, battery-charging

I'm working on a smart watering system for few flowerpots I have in my balcony. My main problem is that I don't have electricity output there, so I'm trying to think of a way to power my Arduino with 12 V somehow. I thought of using 12 V battery and a solar panel, but since I have indirect sun most of the day, and small solar panels are expensive, I dropped the idea. I hoped for some advice, how can I recharge the batteries without direct connection to my home electricity?

Comment: Get a powerbank with solar panel on it. You might still need to charge it from time to time

Comment: You could use rechargeable batteries and charge them inside instead. Would take away the full autonomy of the system, but depending on current draw they wouldn't need to be recharged that often.

Comment: Solar panels don’t need direct sunlight to produce power...

Comment: @SolarMike I'm sorry, I wasn't clear, what I meant was that I didn't find any solar panels in reasonable price that produce enough power to charge 12v batteries. The only panels I found which were efficient enough to use in lighting conditions such as those in my balcony were just too expensive for this project

Comment: Run a telephone cable from your tower to plant system with 12V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make battery powered system. Use 12v battery and buck converter to 5v to save power(instead of using linear voltage regulator which cost much power).

your idea is to make automated watering system>>>> so i suggest you to place water tank in height may be 2 to 3 feet above the pot water level. and use solenoid valve instead of motor pump. and use tip122 to switch ON whenever you want to put water to plants.

are you using any sensor to read water level ? or if your board has more waiting time i suggest you to put your arduino in sleep to save power!!!! use this library [here](https://github.com/n0m1/Sleep_n0m1).

In power saving mode using Arduino board does not help you much. you may need to use barebone.

##################
if you find difficulties, do one thing
if your power plug and balcony is in one digit meter distance, place arduino where you get power. get lengthy wire connect it to switching transistor and valve... Simple...

Comment: A buck converter is a type of voltage regulator.  I think by "Voltage regulator" you might mean "Linear voltage regulator"

Comment: Hit edit and correct your answer and let me know so I can delete my comment.